# I want to change my package name in Android Studio from a .aab file

Tags: android, android-studio, bundle

I am new to Android Development. So, I've been trying to publish my app on Play Store for the past week now. I had no ideas about keys and signing the apps. I went ahead and tried to publish the .aab file but that file got rejected for some reason.

I created multiple new projects with the same code one at a time and due to this, I created multiple keystores, keys, release and debug files.

I couldn't understand what went wrong, so I deleted all the project files and created a brand new one.

So yesterday, Play Console showed that I was signing in with the wrong key.

I remembered that I could restore them from the recycle bin so I did. But now I got a major problem. I have an .aab file which has an incorrect app id and the correct signing key whose ID I need to change in order to publish it on the Play Store. I have a lot of project files so it's really confusing for me to decide which file is which.

So, I need to change the app ID in my .aab file because Play Console won't accept 'com.example' files but I don't have its project.

(I need to change the ID of the .aab file without having any access to it's related files or projects).

Comment: What is the question? In google you can find a lot material about deployment process to playmarket

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename package in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/rename-package-in-android-studio)

Comment: @xicocaio No, I tried doing that. It won't work with an .aab file

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since your App wasn't published. Just delete it and create a new one.

Here is a video how to do it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4aAumiRQTQ4

Also chose a new package name and then make a new .aab

com.example is not allowed because it is too common. It should be a unique package name.

Comment: user want to change his application package name not want to delete application from playstore.